# apt-get update fails in fresh bionic ova image

Tags: apt, 18.04, package-management

Whenever i run apt commands , i get the following error. To note this is a VM in a datacenter

```
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
```

Ping connectivity to the ip succeeds from the VM

```
ping 91.189.91.39
PING 91.189.91.39 (91.189.91.39) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 91.189.91.39: icmp_seq=1 ttl=41 time=219 ms
64 bytes from 91.189.91.39: icmp_seq=2 ttl=41 time=221 ms
64 bytes from 91.189.91.39: icmp_seq=3 ttl=41 time=220 ms
64 bytes from 91.189.91.39: icmp_seq=4 ttl=41 time=219 ms
```

Also the curl connectivity succeeds.

```
curl http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA512

Origin: Ubuntu
Label: Ubuntu
Suite: bionic
Version: 18.04
Codename: bionic
Date: Thu, 26 Apr 2018 23:37:48 UTC
Architectures: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x
Components: main restricted universe multiverse
Description: Ubuntu Bionic 18.04
MD5Sum:
 32a92a5c20f378d42dd2d2f4f28f6637        628836439 Contents-amd64
 53c6a594819b51a5755f88b45d1eff7f         37766986 Contents-arm64.gz
 cd7bf6d50403da4348ee48138eace986        585939706 Contents-ppc64el
 af42d07307c5d1398c75e28986b36509        616261664 Contents-i386
.......so on
```

I have no clue what's going on and this issue has been a show-stopper for me.Can someone please advice on the next steps

Comment: Seems to be because of Network quirkiness that apt is disallowed.Workaround following https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/how-to-set-the-proxy-for-apt-for-ubuntu-18-04/ is succesful

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be because of network quirkiness that apt is disallowed. A workaround following [How to Set the Proxy for apt on Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/how-to-set-the-proxy-for-apt-for-ubuntu-18-04/) was successful.

#### Creating  an apt proxy conf file

`apt` loads all configuration files under `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`. You can create a configuration specifically for your proxy there, keeping it separate from all other configurations.

1. Create a new configuration file named *proxy.conf*.

   ```
   sudo touch /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy.conf
   ```
2. Open the proxy.conf file in a text editor.

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy.conf # or vi instead of nano if you prefer vi
   ```
3. Add the following line to set your HTTP proxy.

   ```
   Acquire::http::Proxy "http://user:password@proxy.server:port/";
   ```
4. Add the following line to set your HTTPS proxy.

   ```
   Acquire::https::Proxy "http://user:password@proxy.server:port/";
   ```
5. Save your changes and exit the text editor.

Your proxy settings will be applied the next time you run apt.

#### Simplifying the configuration

There is an alternative way for defining the proxy settings. While similar it removes some redundancy.

Just like in the first example, create a new file under the `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d` directory, and then add the following lines.

```
Acquire {
  HTTP::proxy "http://127.0.0.1:8080";
  HTTPS::proxy "http://127.0.0.1:8080";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a Proxy. Therefore, I deleted the supplied contents of Proxy.conf. This resolved all of my errors attempting to get updates. Problem solved.